# Where does MAMP keep its web server config file?

Tags: macos, apache, .htaccess, nginx, mamp

I'm using Mac OS X, and I use MAMP for local development. 
I want to modify my web server(`nginx.conf` or `.htaccess`) configuration, and not sure which one/where MAMP place their web server config.

**How do I find out ?**

Any hints ?

Comment: The default Document Root in MAMP is: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs

Answer (score 6):

For MAMP 4.2 the path is: `/Applications/MAMP/conf/nginx/nginx.conf`

Answer (score 1):

Open **Finder** and click on the **Application** Tab, scroll to find the icon shown below:

[image: Mamp Icon]

Then double click this icon to get folder you want.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify for future readers using MAMP PRO:

The base config template is located at ./MAMP/conf/nginx/nginx.conf, but the real/final config is located at /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/conf/nginx.conf

This is the config that includes any of the custom settings for individual Hosts, which might be useful for review/comparison purposes.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using **MAMP PRO 6**, according to the logs you can find the actual (non-template) *NGINX* config file at:

```
/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/conf/nginx.conf
```